# Why does my profile sometimes show the wrong rep for Literature.SE?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

For the past few days, my profile on English.SE and on Meta.SO have intermittently shown 600 rep for my Literature.SE account on the accounts tab:

[image]

However, clicking the link to go to my [Literature profile](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/101/daniel) shows me that I actually have 595 rep there (and have had the [same for four days](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/101/daniel?tab=reputation)):

[image]

Once I've gone to my Literature profile, when I reload the English.SE profile (or the MSO profile), it's gone back to showing 595 rep:

[image]

But after a few minutes (sometimes) or hours (other times), my English and MSO profiles start showing 600 rep for Lit.SE again.  Could someone help me solve the riddle I've been presented with for the last few days?

Comment: The answer is always caching.

Comment: Also, 595 rep and a gold badge? Not bad.

Comment: @JeffMercado and Kevin, what does "caching" mean?  Are you referring to this post or my Literature rep?

Comment: @Daniel: the data you see on a lot of pages are not given to you in real time, basically the server will take snapshots of your status and your snapshot hadn't come in since you last gained rep. It will update soon enough.

Answer (score 2):

We had some issues with cross-site aggregation due to network-level problems a while back, just last night [Monty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose) ran a full network backfill to clean up these discrepancies, you should be all set now.